# Get all fields for record form in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

I have the following LWC

*originationProcess.html*

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-form
        object-api-name={objectApiName}
        record-id={recordId}
        fields={fields}
        columns="2">
    </lightning-record-form>
</template>
```

*originationProcess.js*

```
import { LightningElement, api, wire } from 'lwc';
import OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity';
import NAME_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.Name';
import STAGE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Opportunity.StageName';

export default class OriginationProcess extends LightningElement {
    // Expose a field to make it available in the template
    fields = [NAME_FIELD, STAGE_FIELD];

    // Flexipage provides recordId and objectApiName
    @api recordId;
    @api objectApiName;
}
```

I have to get 30 fields from opportunity. Is there a method to access the fields more easily than importing them 1 by 1? Something like OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT.Name, OPPORTUNITY_OBJECT.StageName and so on and still using the record form?

Answer (score 4):

You can use layout-type instead:

```
<lightning-record-form 
  record-id={recordId} 
  layout-type="Full" 
  object-api-name={objectApiName}>
</lightning-record-form>
```

The layout will be driven by the user's page layout assignment.